# Find duplicates of some keys in array of JavaScript objects and set a related key to true

Tags: javascript, duplicates

I have an array of JS Objects:

```
  var a = [{a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a2",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a3",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false}];
```

I must find duplicates of the last element but WITHOUT considering the key `prop`: when I find them, the related prop boolean must be set to `true`.

I did the simplest thing in the world and it works fine but I was wandering if there is something JS can do (without 3rd party libraries), better either in "elegance", modernity or performance:

```
var toTest = a[a.length-1];
for(var i=0;i<a.length;i++){
      if(toTest.a==a[i].a && toTest.b==a[i].b && toTest.c==a[i].c){
         a[i].prop = true;
         a[a.length-1].prop = true;
      }
    }
```

Any tip is appreciated

Comment: @meowgoesthedog what's a dictionary in JS? Do you mean an object, or a Map?

Comment: You could create an aggregate key for a b and c and put them into a hash, then you just need to check if there is already an entry in the hash when going through the array.

Comment: Can you use es6 ?

Comment: @Logar: yes, I can

Comment: @neuhaus: if you want, you can post i as a solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Array.forEach` and `Array.every`. Create a list of keys to test and in every iteration, check for these keys and update object.

`a[a.length-1].prop = true` looks unnecessary to me as you are not removing the item, so it will be updated in the last iteration.

```js
var a = [{a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
         {a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
         {a:"a",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
         {a:"a2",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
         {a:"a3",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
         {a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false}];
var toTest = a[a.length -1];
var keysToTest = ['a', 'b', 'c'];

a.forEach((o)=>{
  var valid = keysToTest.every((k) => o[k] === toTest[k]);
  if(valid){
    o.prop = true;
  }
});

console.log(a)
```

Comment: Wow, very compact

Answer (score 1):

Use `Array.filter()` with a function that compares only `a`, `b` and `c`.

Edit: I completely replaced my previous answer. I think Array.filter() is the way to go to search for duplicates of the last entry in the array as asked for.

Comment: I don't see how generating a lot of temporary strings and doing a lot of unnecessary string concatenation is an improvement over using `&&`.

Comment: OK I somewhat misread the question, I thought he had to find all duplicates in the array. If you just want to check one value it's better to iterate through it in the simple fashion you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

What you have is pretty much it. There are tweaks you can make, but it's fine as is **except** you want to stop one step earlier, when `i < a.length - 1` (since you don't want to compare the last entry to itself and set `prop` incorrectly).

Some tweaks you *could* do:

- `a[a.length-1].prop = true;` could be `toTest.prop = true;`
- You can cache `a[i]` to a variable rather than looking it up each time
- You can cache `a`, `b`, and `c` instead of looking them up on the object every time (but the JavaScript engine will do that if it matters anyway)
- In ES2015+ you could use destructuring assignment to get `a`, `b`, and `c`

So for instance:

```
// Caching the last item
var last = a[a.length - 1];
// Caching the values to check
var checka = last.a, checkb = last.b, checkc = last.c;
// Stop at i < a.length - 1, caching that to l
for (var i = 0, l = a.length - 1; i < l; ++i) {
    // Cache a[i]
    var entry = a[i];
    if (entry.a == checka && entry.b == checkb && entry.c == checkc) {
        entry.prop = last.prop = true;
    }
}
```

Live Copy:

```js
var a = [{a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a2",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a3",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false}];

// Caching the last item
var last = a[a.length - 1];
// Caching the values to check
var checka = last.a, checkb = last.b, checkc = last.c;
// Stop at i < a.length - 1, caching that to l
for (var i = 0, l = a.length - 1; i < l; ++i) {
    // Cache a[i]
    var entry = a[i];
    if (entry.a == checka && entry.b == checkb && entry.c == checkc) {
        entry.prop = last.prop = true;
    }
}
console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Here's an ES2015+ version, just for reference:

```
const last = a[a.length - 1];
const {a: checka, b: checkb, c: checkc} = last;
for (let i = 0, l = a.length - 1; i < l; ++i) {
    const {a: thisa, b: thisb, c: thisc} = a[i];
    if (thisa == checka && thisb == checkb && thisc == checkc) {
        a[i].prop = last.prop = true;
    }
}
```

Live Copy:

```js
const a = [{a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a2",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a3",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},
           {a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false}];

const last = a[a.length - 1];
const {a: checka, b: checkb, c: checkc} = last;
for (let i = 0, l = a.length - 1; i < l; ++i) {
    const {a: thisa, b: thisb, c: thisc} = a[i];
    if (thisa == checka && thisb == checkb && thisc == checkc) {
        a[i].prop = last.prop = true;
    }
}
console.log(a);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {
  max-height: 100% !important;
}
```

Whether that meets any of your criteria is up to you.

Comment: I won't make an answer for that, but if OP "must find duplicates of the last element but WITHOUT considering the key prop", wouldn't it be better if we loop on object properties instead of manually listing them ?

Comment: @3000: I've updated to include an ES5 and earlier version

Comment: @Logar: If the properties were variable, sure, we'd get the list in advance. From the OP's code I had the impression they were static.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the normal `forEach` Loop

```js
var a = [{a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false}, {a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false}, {a:"a",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false}, {a:"a2",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},{a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false},{a:"a1",b:"b",c:"c",prop:false}];     
var toTest = a[a.length-1];              
a.forEach(function(item){
  item.prop = (item.a == toTest.a && item.b == toTest.b && item.c == toTest.c) ? true : false;
});
console.log(a);
```